# Querying mysql table for times after the current one

Tags: mysql, time

I have a table with 1 column (bus departure times in format "14:32:15"). How to query the table to show only departures that are after the current moment (after curtime())?

E.g.: if it's 12 o'clock and my table has rows (10:15:00,11:20:00,12:30:00, ...), I want to have 12:30:00 returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
`SELECT time FROM yourtable WHERE time > now()`

Comment: Tnx, i guess it was a noob question.